# Can somebody explain this javascript statement to me?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project which needs a lot of javascript coding. And I'm new to Javascript.

Just found a code but can't understand. Can somebody explain to me? I tried to search for answers but turn out with no result.

```
var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
```

I just wanna know what '?' and ':' mean in the above code. And is there any alternative way to write it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a shorthand for and `if / else` statement. I can never remember the name for it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: See my answer, it's called a ternary operator.

Comment: It's **a** ternary opertor, its real name is the [*conditional operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you see is called a **ternary operator**. It is often used when an `if... else...` statement may be unnecessary, or too long. You will see it a lot in conditional variable assignments like the one above.

Basically, the syntax is like this:

`([condition to test] ? [what should we do if true] : [what should we do if false])`.

It is shorthand for

```
if([condition to test]) {
    [what should we do if true];
}
else {
    [what should we do if false];
}
```

In that example, we are trying to assign `var keyCode`. Since some browsers use `e.which` to pass in the numeral value of the key pressed, we have to account for both `e.keyCode` or `e.which`, and assign the appropriate value.

**Also important to note**: `e.keyCode` is not necessarily a boolean value. However, in JavaScript, *any variable* can be interpreted as boolean. `e.keyCode` has boolean value `false` if it's not defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
var keyCode;
if (e.keyCode) {
    keyCode = e.keyCode;
} else {
    keyCode = e.which;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand for if/else.

```
var keyCode;
if (e.keyCode) {
    keyCode = e.keyCode;
} else {
    keyCode = e.which;
}
```